# How to open prevent Activity from finish onBackPress in Android

Tags: android, android-intent

I want to shuffle between 2 activities without finishing anyone of them. I have an Activity 'A' which has a MenuItem 'B'(B is another activity). When I click on MenuItem 'B' an Intent is passsed and Activity 'B' is opened without finishing/killingg Activity 'A'. Now Activity 'B' has a menuItem 'A', on clicking menuItem 'A' the previous Activity should opened instead of creating a new Activity 'A'. My problem is when I opened activity 'A' from Activity'B' and then I again goes to Activity 'B' my app goes to home screen and finishes both the activities. How do I keep these activities in BackStack and prevent them from finishing.

Comment: search activity launcher mode android and look especially for singleTop

Answer (score 0):

Add this flag to your intent:

intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);

Answer (score 0):

It is generally not up to you to decide whether or not an Activity is destroyed or not. Any activity in the back stack may be destroyed by the system due to resource constraints. This is one of the reasons why it is important to correctly implement all activity lifecycle related callbacks.

Please describe why you want to achieve what you're trying to do, because chances are that you have a conceptual error there.

Comment: I have  multiple tabs containing lists of scanned barcode items in both the activities. I want to shuffle between these 2 activities so that I don't lost the tabs and there list

Comment: This is a prime use case for fragments.

Answer (score 0):

May be this will useful .... instated of calling `intent` call `onBackPressed()` to go back activity ( 'A' ).

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    if (id == android.R.id.home) {
        Log.d("TAG", "action bar clicked");
        onBackPressed();
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}



@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    super.onBackPressed();
}
```

Comment: on opening activity 'A' from Activity'B' and then again going to Activity 'B' my app goes to home screen and finishes both the activities

Answer (score 0):

As @metter said

> It is generally not up to you to decide whether or not an Activity is
>   destroyed or not

If you want to keep both your activity A and activity B data. You should use A single activity with a container in the layout. You would then fill the container with Data from activity A or activity B. And for these two activities I suggest you use fragments.